# Why is there a difference in map() between ipython3 and the ipython3 notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

This is the result as expected when I run ipython3 (Python3.2.3) in the shell:

```
In [1]: sum(map(int, str(79)))
Out[1]: 16
```

Now this is the same code in the ipython3 notebook:

```
In [5]: sum(map(int, str(79)))
Out[5]: <builtins.map at 0x5c26950>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: what are `repr(map)` and `repr(sum)` in each context?  Do you have pylab mode or anything set up in either environment?

Comment: @minrk is almost certainly right -- that's what you'd get if you had `sum` replaced by the `numpy` `sum`.  `repr(sum)` won't show this directly (you won't see `<built-in function sum>`, though, which is itself evidence), but `sum.__module__` will probably give `'numpy.core.fromnumeric'`.

Comment: @minrk, @DSM: You are right! I had started the notebook with `ipython3 notebook --pylab inline`. In that case `sum.__module__` will indeed give `'numpy.core.fromnumeric'`, which does behave differently than the builtin version. What would I have to do to have the inline plots, but have numpy not override the builtin functions? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the ipython3 notebook with the `--pylab` option but still have all the builtin functions you can simply do:

```
    In [1]: from builtins import *
```

Thanks to @minrk and @DSM for getting me on the right track here!